How do I make microphone input on MacOS work?
I've set up an "AudioKit" AudioEngine with the below code.
It can play notes with the MIDISampler. However, the PitchTap doesn't seem to get any sample data. It always prints Frequency 100.0 – Amplitude 2.4266092e-05.
final class AudioGraph {
    let engine = AudioEngine()
    let sampler = MIDISampler(name: "sampler")
    let pitchTracker: PitchTap

    init(file: SamplerFile? = nil) throws {
        let mic = engine.input!

        engine.output = Mixer(
            sampler, 
            Fader(mic, gain: 0.000)
        )

        /// Hooking ``PitchTap`` to ``sampler`` works. Yay. Why not the ``mic`` input?
        pitchTracker = PitchTap(mic) { f, a in
            guard let f = f.first, let a = a.first else { return }
            print("Frequency \(f) – Amplitude \(a)")
        }

        if let file {
            try setFile(file)
        }
    }

    func setFile(_ file: SamplerFile) throws {
        try sampler.loadInstrument(url: file.url)
    }
}

// MARK: -

extension AudioGraph: NotePlayer {
    func startAudioEngine() throws {
        print("### Start engine")
        try engine.start()
        pitchTracker.start()
    }
}


I'm experiencing this on iOS 18.1.1 - iPhone 13 mini. Other devices seem to work without a problem.

Here's something to check.

Go to your project target in Xcode.
Go to the "Signing & Capabilities" tab.
Scroll down to "Hardened Runtime", and within that "Resource Access".
Check the "Audio Input" checkbox.


For me, that is what fixed it.
There's nothing in the logs about this, that I saw anyway. No "Wow kid – you're trying to use the microphone, but you've not asked to do that! I'm just going to render silence in to the buffers for you, but you should definitely be asking for access, you know?".
I happened to just notice this checked box in the Cookbook Demo App's project, while randomly looking for some other package dependency settings.
